# PySide using Style Sheets to change QtoolBox

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, maya

I'm Wondering if somebody knows a better reference than the QT one for style sheets.

I try to change the background of the content from a QToolBox but background-color only changes the header of the toolbox and the background of the content it reveals is left in a standard color.

I then tried to change the bg of QWidget which worked but left me with problems now at Radiobuttons and Checkboxes, i also think changing QWidget isn't a good solution.

The first picture is with Qt standard colors (this is a maya tool)
the second when i change QWidget

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRW90.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4RgA.png

Answer (score 0):

> I then tried to change the bg of QWidget which worked but left me with
>   problems now at Radiobuttons and Checkboxes, i also think changing
>   QWidget isn't a good solution.

No man, It is petty good solution. In your `QToolBox` stylesheet, your have use `QWidget {}` it's equivalent to *[class~="QWidget "] so this problem is in subclass has been hanged. To fix it use access specified class like this `*[class="QWidget"] {}`. Example;

```
*[class="QWidget"] {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

[**Useful Qt Stylesheet Reference**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html)

Comment: hmm ok so that thing with the subclass should do it but where do i find out which color i have to change i don't find anywhere a reference of commands for all my widgets only few basic examples with most of the time same commands, its kind a annoying that these settings are not in the documentation

Comment: I don't think so. Qt Style Sheets support all the selectors defined in CSS2. If I want to set complex style sheet, I should do in base CSS2 and reference of this style sheet Qt have explain it. If your want all commands for all my widgets, Your have to read this http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html.